# How to write rscript to to extract URL from HTML table

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to extract every URL like "https://....zip" from the element <a href=""> of the page: https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html using rvest library as follows:

```
link <- "https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html"

library(rvest)
library(xml2)

html <- read_html(link)

html %>% html_attrs("href")
```

Output:

> html %>% html_attrs("href")
> Error in html_attrs(., "href") : unused argument ("href")

Can you please help me using R to extract all URL from the above link?

HTML:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BiFU.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The links are coming from an additional GET request made by the browser which returns xml. You can still go with rvest and grab the Key nodes then complete the urls.

```
library(rvest)

base_url <- "https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com"
files <- read_html(base_url) |> html_elements('key') |> html_text() |> url_absolute(base_url)
```

For older R versions, swop `|>` with `%>%` and add `library(magrittr)` as import.

Comment: Amazing! Look like so easy for you but it made me busy for 2 days googling the solution on the web. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: you are most welcome

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution, using the url back one level to read and parse the xml:

```
# Store as a variable the path url to be scrapped: base_url => character scalar
base_url <- "https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com"

# Resolve the zip urls: zip_urls => character vector
zip_urls <- paste(
  base_url, 
  gsub(
    ">(.*?)<\\/",
    "\\1",
    grep(
      "\\.zip", 
      strsplit(
        readLines(base_url), 
        "\\<Key\\>")[[2]],
      value = TRUE
    )
  ),
  sep = "/"
)
```