# retrieve list of file names from publicly available Amazon S3 bucket using R

Tags: r, amazon-s3

My goal is to download all tifs in a directory in a public Amazon S3 bucket. USGS has started using the Amazon S3 bucket as a way to distribute their 3DEP elevation products. However, I do not want to have to right click and download each file individually. In the past I've retrieved a list of file names in a http folder, create a `df` of full path to files, then used `download.file` to loop through each file and save it. I'm currently having an issue retrieving the list of filenames in the S3 bucket. Here is what I've tried so far...

```
www <- "http://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/WI_AshlandIronFlorence_2019_D19/WI_Ashland_4_2019/TIFF/"

library(rvest)
page <- read_html(www)
files1 <- html_elements(page, xpath = ".//a[contains(@href,'.tif')]") %>% html_text()
print(files1)

library(XML)
files2 <- XML::getHTMLLinks(www, xpQuery = "//a/@href['.tif'=substring(., string-length(.) - 3)]")
print(files2)

library(aws.s3)
bucket_address <- "http://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/WI_AshlandIronFlorence_2019_D19/WI_Ashland_4_2019/TIFF/"
get_bucket_df(bucket = bucket_address)
```

Thanks

Comment: `start_url <- 'http://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/WI_AshlandIronFlorence_2019_D19/WI_Ashland_4_2019/TIFF/' ; read_html(gsub('index\\.html\\?','?delimiter=/&', start_url)) %>% html_elements('key') %>% html_text() %>% url_absolute(start_url)` but check this file for possible other cases `http://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/web/js/list.js`

Comment: This code works. Could you post it as answer and explain why/how your read_html code works?

Comment: I think it was similar to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384812/6241235  hence my not posting as an answer. However, I actually looked through the js file to see what is was doing; only after doing that did I realise it is broadly similar to an earlier answer I had written. I think there might be some edge cases but I only really skimmed the js file, I can write up if you want more of an explanation though would be tomorrow.