# Web-scraping multiple dissimilar pages

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

Given a set of URLs that do not have any common underlying structure, in terms of their HTML code, and a keyword, which R packages are best recommended to use to explore all the links within those pages - Rvest or Rcrawler- in terms of speed and efficiency? Any ideas for Python?

Comment: [What to ask instead of “is it possible to ...”](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution you are expecting is something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384812/12050737

But, by adding a few codes as follows, we can solve the problem:

```
library(rvest)
base_url <- "https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com"
files <- read_html(base_url) |> html_elements('key') |> html_text() |> url_absolute(base_url)
keyword <- "2021"
results <- grepl(keyword,files); results ## TRUE means the keyword was found
files[results] ## the result as containing characters
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).